# Error in JSON file reading : write() argument must be str, not generator

Tags: python, json, string-formatting, file-handling

I'm reading content from a JSON file and appending it to a text file . I'm getting the following error :

**' write() argument must be str, not generator '**  when I run this code and I'm not able to correct it .

```
with open('stackExchangeAPI.json','r') as json_file:
    tags_list = []
    data = json.load(json_file)
    for i in range(0,99):
        for j in range(0,99):
          tags = data[i]["items"][j]["tags"]
          with open('tags.txt','a+') as tags_file:
                tags_file.seek(0)
                d = tags_file.read(100)
                if len(d) > 0 :
                    tags_file.write("\n")
                tags_file.write(f'{tags[i]}' for i in range(0,(len(tags)-1)))
```

The error is **from the last line ' tags_file.write(f'......) '**

Can someone please help me rectify this ?

Comment: `tags_file.write(''.join(f....`.  You are writing a generator, you need to write a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says, you are trying to `write` a generator, you must first convert it to a string, probably by using `join`:

```
out = ''.join(f'{tags[i]}' for i in range(0,(len(tags)-1)))
tags_file.write(out)
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to write the for loop to the file. Try changing the last line to:

```
[tags_file.write(f'{tags[i]}') for i in range(0,(len(tags)-1))]
```